# Object reverts back to non-modified state after joining

Tags: modifiers, objects

I am attempting to make a tree but when I try to join the different components together <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> my decimated icospheres revert back to its original shape.  Any idea on how I can solve this?  I also forgot to mention that I am trying to create a low poly tree and that I am still in the learning stages.

The first image is the tree before joining and the second is the tree after joining

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like what is happening is this. On the two green objects of your tree, you added a *Decimate* modifier, but before joining the objects you did not apply the modifier. On the "trunk" of the tree you do not have a *Decimate*, so when joining the objects the modifier is removed.

To apply the modifier, in object mode, just click on the *apply* button on the modifier.
[image: apply modifier]

Answer (score 7):

The object(s) that you select ***before*** the last object with the modifier will discard their modifier stack and inherit that *(the last)* object's modifier stack.

Easiest way to avoid any loss of modifiers is to apply them before doing any joins.