# How to join different objects (different modifiers)

Tags: objects

What I would like to do is a merge of two objects without applying their own and distinct modifiers.

In other words: the first object has Sub.Surface modifier active but not applied, the second one does not have any modifier. Can I somehow join them without losing the sub.surface of the first object and avoiding the second object getting that modifier as well? (I wouldn't like to apply sub.surface before joining them)

Thanks

Comment: The short and simple answer is: no.

Comment: Similar question, [Object reverts back to non-modified state after joining](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14901/2217).

Comment: It was exactly what I hoped not to hear... but also what I expected =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the joined mesh CREASE where you wish to limit the subsurf effect:

[image]

with CREASE 1.0 subsurf has no effect at all...

Comment: Thanks for your help!
However "crease" doesn't really solve my problem... I forgot to mention that the main aim is to keep the vertex number of the second object lower than that of the first one. Keeping your example: the two cubes are a single object, one is normally affected by subsurf while the other is bent by "crease"... anyway they both have their vertex number increased, isn't it?

Comment: ok, I understand. But what is the strong reason for the need to "join" them? they could be parented, instead, or have constraints to copy location or trasforms... but modifers act on all of the object mesh...

Comment: Since the goal is to import the fbx in UnrealEngine4, I think that having two distinct objects would be a bit more troublesome for what concerns the lightmaps... I would like them to have exactly the same response to the light! If I join them there will be no problem!